# Using .BINDING File with MDB in Jboss EAP6.4

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

I am writing a standard Java EE 5 application and need to consume JMS messages (HornetQ) from MQ serverv8. MQ admin has provided a .bindings file as MQ configuration. After searching web, I am not able to find a way to use .bidings file with MDBs. have already tried using standard activation spec. That works fine. But for that, JMS properties need to be in JBOSS or EE specific configuration files. Can someone please tell a way to use .bindings file with MDB?

How to decide the jndi and initial context factory name ?

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to use a .bindings file with an MDB activation specification, this turns out to be impractical.  You can specify the destination in both the .bindings file and the MDB activation spec, but not the connection factory.  The attributes that configure the connection factory (i.e. the host, port, channel, etc.) are configured individually in the activation spec.

What you can do is to use the .bindings file to configure a JMS messaging bridge from MQ to JBoss.  Then, your MDB just listens on a local HornetQ destination.  In order to get this working, you need to:

1) Create an IBM MQ client module.  The messaging bridge will not be using the IBM JCA.  On a UNIX MQ server, you will find the client jars in the `/opt/mqm/java/lib/` directory.

I created a module with the following jar files:

```
./system/layers/base/com/ibm/wmqclient75
./system/layers/base/com/ibm/wmqclient75/main
./system/layers/base/com/ibm/wmqclient75/main/com.ibm.mq.tools.ras.jar
./system/layers/base/com/ibm/wmqclient75/main/com.ibm.mq.axis2.jar
./system/layers/base/com/ibm/wmqclient75/main/com.ibm.mq.headers.jar
./system/layers/base/com/ibm/wmqclient75/main/ldap.jar
./system/layers/base/com/ibm/wmqclient75/main/CL3Nonexport.jar
./system/layers/base/com/ibm/wmqclient75/main/providerutil.jar
./system/layers/base/com/ibm/wmqclient75/main/connector.jar
./system/layers/base/com/ibm/wmqclient75/main/jta.jar
./system/layers/base/com/ibm/wmqclient75/main/com.ibm.mq.soap.jar            
./system/layers/base/com/ibm/wmqclient75/main/com.ibm.mq.jms.Nojndi.jar
./system/layers/base/com/ibm/wmqclient75/main/com.ibm.mq.jar
./system/layers/base/com/ibm/wmqclient75/main/com.ibm.mqjms.jar
./system/layers/base/com/ibm/wmqclient75/main/rmm.jar
./system/layers/base/com/ibm/wmqclient75/main/jms.jar
./system/layers/base/com/ibm/wmqclient75/main/com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar
./system/layers/base/com/ibm/wmqclient75/main/fscontext.jar
./system/layers/base/com/ibm/wmqclient75/main/com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar
./system/layers/base/com/ibm/wmqclient75/main/CL3Export.jar
./system/layers/base/com/ibm/wmqclient75/main/jndi.jar
./system/layers/base/com/ibm/wmqclient75/main/com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar
./system/layers/base/com/ibm/wmqclient75/main/dhbcore.jar
./system/layers/base/com/ibm/wmqclient75/main/module.xml
```

My module.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.ibm.wmqclient75">
<resources>
<resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar" />
<resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.headers.jar" />
<resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.jar" />
<resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar" />
<resource-root path="com.ibm.mqjms.jar" />
<resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar" />

<resource-root path="connector.jar" />
<resource-root path="dhbcore.jar" />
<resource-root path="fscontext.jar"/>
<resource-root path="providerutil.jar"/>
</resources>

<dependencies>
   <!-- add the dependencies required by JMS Bridge code                -->
   <module name="javax.api"/>
   <module name="javax.resource.api"/>
   <module name="javax.jms.api"/>
   <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
   <module name="org.jboss.remote-naming"/>
   <!-- we depend on org.hornetq module since we will send messages to  -->
   <!-- the HornetQ server embedded in the local AS7 instance           -->
   <module name="org.hornetq"/>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

2) You can then load configure your bridge:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.4">
....
....
....
            <jms-bridge name="wmqBridge" module="com.ibm.wmqclient75">
            <target>
                <connection-factory name="XAConnectionFactory"/>
                <destination name="jms/queue/test"/>
            </target>
            <source>
                <connection-factory name="mqCF"/>
                <destination name="mqQueue"/>
                <context>
                    <property key="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory"/>
                    <property key="java.naming.provider.url" value="file:///${jboss.server.data.dir}/bindings/"/>
                </context>
            </source>
            <quality-of-service>ONCE_AND_ONLY_ONCE</quality-of-service>
            <failure-retry-interval>500</failure-retry-interval>
            <max-retries>1</max-retries>
            <max-batch-size>1</max-batch-size>
            <max-batch-time>1000000</max-batch-time>
            <add-messageID-in-header>true</add-messageID-in-header>
        </jms-bridge>
    </subsystem>
```

Note that I refernnce my module:

```
<jms-bridge name="wmqBridge" module="com.ibm.wmqclient75">
```

My names for the destination and connection factory, as found in the .bindings file:

```
                <connection-factory name="mqCF"/>
                <destination name="mqQueue"/>
```

I created a directory under the standard data directory named `bindings` and placed the .bindings file in it:

```
<property key="java.naming.provider.url" value="file:///${jboss.server.data.dir}/bindings/"/>
```

That will get your messages locally on a destination that you can access.

- Doug